# Access a list inside a dictionary from input

Tags: python, list, dictionary, input

So I´m trying to get access to a list inside of a dictionary. The "Key", comes from input and my program should search through the dictionary´s list with help from a for loop to see if the input matches a key and in that case print out the list(values). However when I try this, with the code below. The program gives me the wrong information (wrong names and not the right amount)

```
if val == 2:
  val2 = input("Enter a name: ")
  for value in likes:
      if val2 in likes[value]:
          print (val2 + " likes " + value)
```

Here's the dictionary

```
likes = {'Augusta':['Charmain','Billie','Mandy','Charlotte','Lesley'],'Charmain':['Augusta','Mandy'],'Billie':['Augusta','Charmain','Lesley',],'Mandy':['Charlotte','Billie','Augusta'],'Lesley':['Billie']}
```

The for loop always gives me the same result, but it isn't correct.

If I enter it like this, the correct list appears. However since the program is depending on input, it's not alternative.

```
print(likes['Augusta'])
```

What should I do?

Comment: val2 is the key of a list inside of the dictionary and I want the program to enter the value. Not the key. The information that should be printed out is who "val2" likes, which the list consists of. Augusta likes Charmain, Billie etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea (almost a **must**) to name your variables in a way that they indicate what they represent. Your solution is very very simple:

```
inputName = input("Enter a name: ")
print(inputName + " likes " + ', '.join(likes[inputName]))
```

Let's try:

```
Enter a name: Augusta
Augusta likes Charmain, Billie, Mandy, Charlotte, Lesley
```

Comment: The program shouldn't write who likes inputName. It should write out all of the people that inputName likes. The question to be answered is: Who do x like? - "Enter a name". Sorry if I wasn't being distinct enough

Comment: Then my comment was right, you are indeed looking for `print(likes[val2])`, and you want the program to enter the **key** not the value. Values are those lists, and you want keys to be entered, values to be returned. Please see my edit.

Comment: @hannasamuelsson Please feel free to clarify further if my understanding is not right.